# C# - Não consigo mapear HERANÇA com o Entity Framework Core - Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Não estou conseguindo mapear as classes Pessoa e Cliente (`Table Per Type` (`TPT`) usando o `Entity Framework Core`), sendo que Cliente herda de Pessoa.

Como faço?

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
}


public class Cliente : Pessoa
{
}

public DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoa { get; set; }
public DbSet<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }

public void PessoaMapping(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
       modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>()
                .ToTable("tblPessoa");

       modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>()
                .HasKey(p => p.PessoaId);

       modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>()
                .Property(p => .PessoaId).ValueGeneratedNever();
}

public void ClienteMapping(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>()
             .ToTable("tblCliente");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criada as classes é só configurar no seu contexto no método `OnModelCreating` ou até por [DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx), esse exemplo minimo é configurado pelo método `OnModelCreating`:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente: Pessoa
{
    public string CPF { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class Ctx: DbContext
{
    public Ctx()
    {
        //Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoa { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {            
        string cn = "Server=.\\SQLExpress;Database=MyDataBaseEntityCore;";
        cn += "User Id=sa;Password=senha;";

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(cn, c =>
        {

        });
    }

    //configurando as classes
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>()
            .ToTable("Pessoa")
            .ForSqlServerToTable("Pessoa")
            .HasKey(x => x.PessoaId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>()
            .Property(x => x.PessoaId)
            .IsRequired()
            .UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>()
            .Property(x => x.Nome)
            .HasMaxLength(100)
            .IsRequired();


        modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>()
            .ForSqlServerToTable("Cliente")
            .ToTable("Cliente");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>()
            .Property(x => x.CPF)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(20);

    }
}
```

Um ponto a observar é que essa versão (`1.1.2`) do Entity Framework Core, mesmo configurando as tabelas, não gera uma tabela para cada tipo (como foi pedido na pergunta), e sim um campo `Discriminator` para identificar a qual tipo pertence aquele registro, acredito ser uma limitação ainda da versão.

***Observações:*** *Só lembrando que essa configuração é para `Entity Framework Core 1.1.2` para o banco `SQLServer`, sendo essa a mais estável, mas, está no forno quase pronto a versão `2.0.0`, que trará muitas mudanças.*

***Operações:***

- Adicionar novo `Cliente`:

  ```
  using (Ctx c = new Ctx())
  {
      c.Pessoa.Add(new Cliente
      {
          CPF = "111.111.111-11",
          Nome = "StackOverFlow Core"
      });
      c.SaveChanges();
  }
  ```
- Editar `Cliente` do `PessoaId = 1`:

  ```
  using (Ctx c = new Ctx())
  {
       Cliente cliente = c.Pessoa
          .OfType<Cliente>()
          .FirstOrDefault(x => x.PessoaId == 1);

      if (cliente != null)
      {
          cliente.Nome = "StackOverFlow Core + Update";
          c.SaveChanges();
      }    
  }
  ```
- Excluir `Cliente` do `PessoaId = 1`:

  ```
  using (Ctx c = new Ctx())
  {
      Cliente cliente = c.Pessoa
          .OfType<Cliente>()
          .FirstOrDefault(x => x.PessoaId == 1);
      if (cliente != null)
      {
          c.Pessoa.Remove(cliente);
          c.SaveChanges();
      }                
  }
  ```
- Buscar `Cliente` do `PessoaId = 2`:

  ```
  using (Ctx c = new Ctx())
  {
      Cliente cliente = c.Pessoa
          .OfType<Cliente>()
          .FirstOrDefault(x => x.PessoaId == 2);
      if (cliente != null)
      {

      }                
  }
  ```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Getting started with ASP.NET Core MVC and Entity Framework Core using Visual Studio (1 of 10)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro)
- [DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [EF Core -  Iniciando com o Entity Framework Core - I](http://www.macoratti.net/17/05/efcore_ini1.htm)
- [Entity Framework Core: Criando bases de dados com Migrations](http://www.devmedia.com.br/entity-framework-core-criando-bases-de-dados-com-migrations/36776)

Comment: Obrigado Virgilio Novic. Tentei de tudo, mas não funcionou. Infelizmente, como vc disse, deve ser ainda uma limitação da versão. Vou aguardar... :)